# Downloading a file using PowerShell - Redirected

Tags: powershell, automation, invoke-webrequest

I have a URL that sends me to a "preparing your download" page, and then triggers a file download.
I need to be able to use PowerShell to script the download of the generated file.
This surely must be possible, but I have no idea how to achieve it.

There is a button that appears once the file is generated "Try again", perhaps it is possible to use that link to download the file, or is there some other way to achieve this?

I found this elsewhere and tried to use it, but it produces an error.

Code:

```
$destination = "C:\Temp\TeamViewer.exe"
$source=Invoke-WebRequest https://get.teamviewer.com/6******** -MaximumRedirection 0
$sourceadw = $source.Links | where {$_.innerText -eq "Try again"} | select -expand href
Invoke-WebRequest $sourceadw -OutFile $destination
```

Error:

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErJT7.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Just ignore the filename in the image.. :)

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.